# Try/Except Syntax in APL

Tags: try-catch, apl, dyalog

How to use Try/Except in APL

Using `:Trap` is not working, Why and how to fix?

Code:

```
∇F←R
:Trap
⎕←1÷0
:Catch
⎕←'Error'
:EndTrap
F←0
∇
R
```